# docker-compose run does not set links

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file along the lines of:

```
analytics:
    build: .
    links:
    - mongo:mongo
    ports:
    - 80:80
mongo:
    build: docker_containers/mongo
    expose:
    - 27017
```

Running `docker-compose up` creates a link in `/etc/hosts` to the `mongo` service. However, running `docker-compose run analytics bash` does not create the link -- I checked the `/etc/hosts` file.

The docs of docker-compose do not mention anything about this, so I'm confused.

1. Why isn't the link set when using `run`?
2. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Same issue here. The bug got closed because there was no extra information added. Perhaps you could get this re-opened?

Answer (score 3):

My take on the answers:

1. It's a bug.
2. See if it's fixed in an [unreleased version of docker-compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) or [create an issue asking that the bug be fixed](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/new).

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the release notes. I opened https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1276. Thanks!

Comment: Confirming that it's a bug, since [the doc](http://docs.docker.com/compose/cli/#run) says "by default, linked services will also be started". Opening an issue was the right thing to do!

Answer (score 1):

I only have an answer for the question number 2. Start the whole environment using `docker-compose run` and then execute `docker exec` in the analytics container

```
docker exec -ti $analytics_container_id bash
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was starting the mongo container with `docker-compose up -d mongo` and then running my command with `docker-compose run analytics [...]`. Thanks!